# How do I SELECT the 5 highest values in an integer column?

Tags: mysql

What is the correct SQL statement if i wish to select the biggest 5 integer rows in the column "id"?

Currently i have something which is only getting id that are less than 5:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < 5
```

Comment: You want the first 5? or the biggest 5 integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @exxcellent: Since nobody's actually explained why `id < 5` is different from `LIMIT 5`, I'll try. `id<5` actually does a comparison of every value of `id`. If you change the comparison to `id<10` and `id<15` you can watch how the results change. `LIMIT 5`, on the other hand, truncates the entire result set to only the first 5 results. That's why you have to also use `ORDER BY id DESC` to guarantee that the first 5 results are the `id` values with the highest values.

Comment: @KurtMcKee you are absolutely correct but here exxcellent didn't want any explanation so that no one give the explanation. I think here who give the answer all are known about this explanation. whatever thanks.

Answer (score 2):

5 largest "id" values:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly , i think you need this,

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 5 * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC
```